# Castle Windsor with .net 4 framework, Silverlight 4

Tags: .net, castle-windsor

I want to use Windsor container and its silverlight version in my .net 4.0 framework and silverlight 4.0 solution. I even compiled the source code for .net 4 but unit tests didnt pass. Has anybody tried to do this?

I also tried Unity IOC framework and that doesnt even compile.

Comment: if Unity can suit, you can download it for SL4 within CAL(Prism) http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=387c7a59-b217-4318-ad1b-cbc2ea453f40&displaylang=en

Comment: We will start .NET 4 builds very soon. If you would like to contribute by testing or providing patches that would be more than welcome.

Answer (score 0):

It's currently [work in progress](http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-devel/browse_thread/thread/65634b42d883f798). I invite you to hop in and help out!

At least please list the tests that didn't pass. Thanks!